# Laravel raw subquery same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `Users` with these columns:

```
     $users = User::select(['id','name','level','parent','updated_at'])
     ->where('level','>',1)
     ->get();
```

Output:

```
      id   name      level       parent   updated_at
      ----+---------+-----------+--------+-------------
      12   Jhon      1           0        2016-02-01
      99   Carl      2           12       2016-02-01
```

Then: I try this for show column `parent` how name `id` associated for example, in second row, show `Jhon` replacing `12`.

I tried this code:

```
     $users = User::select(['id','name','level',
       DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = users.parent"),
       'updated_at'])
     ->where('level', '>', 1)
     ->get();
```

Expected Output:

```
      id   name      level       parent   updated_at
      ----+---------+-----------+--------+-------------
      12   Jhon      1                    2016-02-01
      99   Carl      2           Jhon     2016-02-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `leftJoin` to get the parent name:

```
$users = User::select(['users.id','users.name','users.level', 'parent.name')
 ->leftJoin('users AS parent','users.parent','=','parent.id')
 ->where('users.level','>',1)
 ->get();
```